# how dynamically assign ring color

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapes, ring

we could define a ring drawable and use it in layout xml file, as sample copied below,

is it possible to define a ring drawable and in runtime change the color dynamically? The use case is in the list item it may have different ring color for the ring in different item.

search and could not find a good solution, appreciated if someone have some suggestions.

```
<ImageView
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ring" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:top="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#4d4d4d" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#4d4d4d"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Try my answer.. working fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **First Put the Id to your layer draw able like that**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/shape1"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#4d4d4d" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/shape2"

        >
        <shape

            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#4d4d4d"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    </layer-list>
```

> **Code...**

```
LayerDrawable shape = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(demo.this,R.drawable.ring);
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable1 = (GradientDrawable) shape.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.shape1);

GradientDrawable gradientDrawable2 = (GradientDrawable) shape.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.shape2);

gradientDrawable1.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(demo.this,R.color.color_first));

gradientDrawable2.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(demo.this,R.color.color_second));// changing to black color

ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
imageView.setBackground(shape);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Arjun! what if the ring drawable has one shape with two colors: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring" android:useLevel="false">
    <solid
        android:color="#ee8838" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ff0000" />
</shape>

Comment: Today I am not on pc but you can try with take color shape in <item>  and set id to item and than set color.....

Comment: Also there are some method if ring have two color one two overall which is changed with answer and also if want to stock color change with this method shape.setStroke(strokeWidth,color) set width int and color like upper answer....